# Методы DAO срабатывают лишь один раз

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao

Внес исправления в [предыдущее обращение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634720/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-jdbc-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%94) и сейчас обратил внимание что мои методы работы с ДАО отрабатывают только один раз. Прошу объяснить как исправить данную проблему. Как правильно закрывать `connection` и как правильно с ним работать.

```
package com.oleg.dao.impl;

import com.oleg.dao.UserDao;
import com.oleg.first.User;

import java.sql.*;

public class UserDatabaseDao implements UserDao {
    private final Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement getByIdStmt;
    private PreparedStatement updateStmt;
    private PreparedStatement addStmt;
    private PreparedStatement deleteStmt;

User user = new User();

public UserDatabaseDao(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    this.con = con;

    getByIdStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?");
    updateStmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE user SET nickname=?, firstName=?, secondName=?, WHERE id=?");
    addStmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (nickname, firstName, secondName, password, email)" +
            " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    deleteStmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM user WHERE id=?");

}

private User getUser(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    User user = new User();

    user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    user.setNickname(rs.getString("nickname"));
    user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
    user.setSecondName(rs.getString("secondName"));
    user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
    user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));

    return user;
}

public User getById(int id) throws SQLException {
    User user = null;
    try {
        getByIdStmt.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = getByIdStmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            user = getUser(rs);
        }
        rs.close();
        getByIdStmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        getByIdStmt.close();
    }
    return user;
}

public void update(User user) throws SQLException {
    try {
        updateStmt.setInt(4, user.getId());
        updateStmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        updateStmt.close();
    }
}

public void add(User user) throws SQLException {
    try {
        addStmt.setString(1, user.getNickname());
        addStmt.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
        addStmt.setString(3, user.getSecondName());
        addStmt.setString(4, user.getPassword());
        addStmt.setString(5, user.getEmail());
        addStmt.executeUpdate();
        addStmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        addStmt.close();
    }
}

public void delete(int id) throws SQLException {
    try {
        deleteStmt.setInt(1, id);
        deleteStmt.executeUpdate();
        deleteStmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        deleteStmt.close();
    }
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Закрывать нужно как методе getById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У данного класса нет ответственности в создании подключения к базе данных (он его получает извне в конструкторе), значит он не должен его закрывать. Закрытие должно происходить на уровне ее открытия.
Это к вопросу о правильном закрытии подключения.

В методах `getById(int id)`, `update(User user)` первой же строкой удаляешь подключение к базе (`Connection con = null;`) удивительно, что 1 раз отрабатывает данный класс.

Comment: внес небольшие правки. Имеет ли смысл создавать подключение в данном классе?

Comment: Создание коннекшена достаточно затратная процедура (50-200мс на моем ноуте). Поэтому хорошей практикой считается создание пула подключений в слое сервисов и многократное их использование. К тому же транзакция опирается обычно так же на бизнес логику, а не на логику обращения к базе, т.е. обработка нескольких обращений к базе, что так же исключает ответственность дао слоя за создание и закрытие подключений к базе.